# Number of solutions of an IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=60y^{\dfrac{2}{5}}$ ,$x\gt 0$ ,$y(0)=0$ has

1.a unique solution.

2.two solutions.

3.no solution.

4.infinite number of solutions.

Here f(x,y)=$60y^{\dfrac{2}{5}}$ does not satisfy Lipschitz's condition, so I can't give any conclusion about the uniqueness of the solution. how can I get all possible solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [seperation of variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables) to obtain the solutions: The constant function $y \equiv 0$ solves the IVP. Assuming that $y \not\equiv 0$, we can compute
$$y^{-2/5} \frac{dy}{dx} = 60$$
at all points where $y \neq 0$. Integrating this equation with respect to $x$ gives us
$$\int y^{-2/5} \frac{dy}{dx} ~ dx = \int 60 ~ dx$$
The left side equals
$$\int y^{-2/5} ~ dy = \frac{5}{3} y^{3/5} + c ~ , ~ c \in \mathbb{R}.$$
The right side equals
$$\int 60 ~ dx = 60 x + d ~ , ~ d \in \mathbb{R}.$$
Merging both constants $c,d$ into one (new) constant $c$ we get 
$$y(x) = \left( 36 x + c \right)^\frac{5}{3} ~ , ~ c \in \mathbb{R}.$$

Now, for $c > 0$ let 
$$y_c(x) = \left\lbrace \begin{array}{cl} 0 & , ~ 0 \leq x \leq c \\ (36x-36c)^{\frac{5}{3}} &, ~ c < x \end{array} \right.$$
Then $y_c' = 60 y_c^{2/5}$ and $y_c(0) = 0$. Hence, there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: How can I confirm that there are exactly two solutions?

Comment: @Panja.S. Sorry, I realized that one can use compositions of both solutions to obtain infinitely many. Fixed it in my answer.